# Validating with a REL attribute

Tags: html, xhtml

I have one last error remaining but I need the rel attribute. Is there a way to have it and still get my code valid?

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkansasoutlawwrestling.com%2F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `<div>` elements simply don't have a `rel` attribute in XHTML.

Your best bet is to change the `<div>` to an `<a>`, since looking at your page it's apparent that you want to make it a navigation item (and while you're at it, add a `href`, some text, and use additional CSS to hide it to let your image show through):

```
<a class="nav_click" id="navi1" rel="home" href="/index.html">Home</a>
```

Comment: In fact, while I'm not a doctor, your page seems to have a very bad case of [divitis](http://csscreator.com/divitis).